# subtotal 103 if meets particular condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an array formula that is looking for a maximum value in specified range of cells. In this case I have a value in cell A2 (Polish). Of course, I run the formula pressing ctrl+shift+eneter.

I use MAX formula to find the higest value in Sheet 2:

```
{=MAX(IF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$74=A2;Sheet2!$C$2:$C$74))}
```

I'd like to do the same with MIN formula so I need to find the lowest value except 0. My working formula is below:

```
{=MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(103;OFFSET(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$74;ROW(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$74)-ROW(Sheet2!$C$2);0;1));IF(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$74>0;Sheet2!$C$2:$C$74)))}
```

The problem is that it is taking into consideration all values, not the values from specified range. I need to add IF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$74=A2 so it is looking for min value only in range specified in cell A2 but I don't know where to put this piece of formula.I tried to use AND in last IF formula but it doesn't work.

```
{=MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(103;OFFSET(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$74;ROW(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$74)-ROW(Sheet2!$C$2);0;1));IF(AND(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$74>0;Sheet2!$B$2:$B$74=A2);Sheet2!$C$2:$C$74)))}
```

The sample Excel file can be downloaded [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00392286677385894454).

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer to my question. I just overcomplicated the formula. Please see the working formula below:

```
=MIN(IF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$76=A2;IF(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$76>0;SHeet2!$C$2:$C$76)))
```

Comment: I didn't notice that you had posted this - yes this works fine as well. =MIN(IF((Sheet2!$B$2:$B$76=A2)*(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$76>0),Sheet2!$C$2:$C$76)) is another option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Subtotal/offset combination (though powerful) is particularly helpful in this particular case - I would recommend using Aggregate:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,Sheet2!C$2:C$73/((Sheet2!C$2:C$73>0)*(Sheet2!B$2:B$73=A2)),1)
```

[image]